# Hardcode Initial Data to Redux store in Django/React app

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I have a React-Redux app which currently makes an API call to my Django backend to receive data to be displayed on a dashboard.

The problem I am having is with data size and load times. Currently, the entire JSON packet is around 6MB and the total request time is around 1.5-2 minutes.

I noticed that when I hardcode the "initial data" to the same data packet within my Redux Reducer, the load time is instantaneous.

My question is- is there any existing methods that exist that would allow me to either periodically update this "Initial Data" from the backend.

Or are any other recommended methods to speed this data transfer up?

Unfortunately I cannot use pagination, as I need the entire data packet for the React app to work efficiently.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you can save the data in the local storage or lazy loading. if you want to use "initial data" you will need to update the front.

Comment: @Omer using local storage seems like it may be a good option- though I would still have the problem of load times whenever the user wanted the most recent data or upon the first load.

Comment: yes you can show the local storage data until 1.5-2 sec then the data updated by server.. and write for the costumer the last time update.. 14.04.2020 and loading updated data... and then when you get the server, you show him 16.04.2020, and data is up to date.. or something like that :)

Comment: @Omer That might just be crazy enough to work! :) I'll give it a shot, thanks for the comments!